# replace domain name in htaccess rule with dynamic hostname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule in `htaccess`:

```
1 ## Protect from spam bots ##
2 RewriteEngine On
3 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
4 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
5 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.DOMAIN.COM.* [OR]
6 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
7 RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
```

I want to replace the **DOMAIN.COM** at line 5 with dynamic hostname.
I would like to use the same rule with other domain without having to modify `htaccess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.DOMAIN.COM.* [OR]
> ```

The complexity comes about because server variables of the form `%{HTTP_HOST}` are not expanded in the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive), since it is a *PCRE* (regular expression).

Instead of the above line, you can do something like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*?)@@https?://\1/ [OR]
```

This checks that the requested `Host` header matches the *hostname* part of the HTTP `Referer` header.

The `\1` backreference (in the Referer) matches against the Host. The `@@` string is just any unique string that cannot otherwise occur.

Note that it is possible for legitimate users to not send an HTTP `Referer` header at all, in which case your current ruleset will also *fail*.

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
> ```

Note that the *substitution* string in your `RewriteRule` is malformed. It is an "ordinary" string, not a regex. Consequently, the anchors `^` and `$` will be seen as literal characters and should be removed:

```
RewriteRule .* http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/ [R=301,L]
```